# MySQL INSERT INTO ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE Failing with Composite Primary Key

Tags: mysql

I have the following table in a MySQL 8.0 database (multiple fields left out of the table below) with a composite primary key that I cannot update using `INSERT INTO ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`

```sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS db.entries (
  id VARCHAR(36) NOT NULL COMMENT 'UUID',
  scenario VARCHAR(36) NOT NULL COMMENT 'UUID',
  archive BOOLEAN NOT NULL DEFAULT FALSE,
  PRIMARY KEY (id, scenario)
);
```

I execute the query

```sql
INSERT INTO db.entries VALUES (?, ?, ?) as new
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
archive = new.archive;
```

and receive the following error (sample) when changing the `archive` flag to `TRUE` and saving the entry.

```
Error 1062 (23000): Duplicate entry '14a80111-eaf6-4b58-8803-7ec10f6a61c9-77bc657d-e81d-4ea8-8dbc-ce1' for key 'entries.PRIMARY'
```

I expected the query's `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` to update the entry's archive status to TRUE vice throwing an error. I suspect the composite `PRIMARY KEY` is where my problem is lurking. I have researched the problem in depth in MySQL's documentation and on Stack Exchange but none of the solutions I could find involved composite `PRIMARY` keys and `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`

Update.

I removed the `?` from `VALUES` substituting in the actual values and it seems to work, but not sure why the difference.

```sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS entriesTest (
    id VARCHAR(36) NOT NULL,
    scenarioId VARCHAR(36) NOT NULL,
    archive BOOLEAN NOT NULL DEFAULT FALSE,
    PRIMARY KEY (id,scenarioId)
);

INSERT INTO entriesTest (id, scenarioId, archive) VALUES ('1', '1', FALSE);
INSERT INTO entriesTest (id, scenarioId, archive) VALUES ('2', '1', FALSE);
INSERT INTO entriesTest (id, scenarioId, archive) VALUES ('3', '1', FALSE);

INSERT INTO entriesTest (id, scenarioId, archive) VALUES ('1', '1', TRUE) as t
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE archive = t.archive;
```

Comment: Is it possible the key is already somehow duplicated? I've seen MySQL databases get into that state and it's only fixable with [`REPAIR TABLE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/repair-table.html).

Comment: tadman I encountered the error performing an integration test. It spins up a completely new database every test. The table starts off empty. I add an entry, change the archive flag, and execute the query above, but receive the duplicate entry error. I would expect it to just update the `archive` flag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, it turns out someone on the team decided to setup an update based SQL trigger that inserted the new entry into an identically named table in the `audit` database. The duplicate key error triggered when attempting to insert the new entry into the table in the `audit` schema. Since SQL does not provide a schema or database qualifier before the table identified in the error, we changed the name of the table in the audit database to make it easier to track down future errors. Bottom line...MySQL 8.0 and Go are working just fine!

Answer (score 1):

I tried it in local Mysql 5.7, with a working code, cannot test with Mysql 8.

I don't know about the row alias `VALUES(?, ?, ?) as new`, but Mysql has a good way of reusing the original data passed for each row with `VALUES(col_name)` https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html , like:

```
INSERT INTO t1 (a,b,c) VALUES (1,2,3),(4,5,6)
  ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE c=VALUES(a)+VALUES(b);
```

Here is the full SQL codes. First I entered `id1-scenario1` with archive `false`. And at the bottom, I re-entered the same, but with archive `true`, it updated it to true, with no problem:

```
create database mydb;
use mydb;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS entries (
  id VARCHAR(36) NOT NULL COMMENT 'UUID',
  scenario VARCHAR(36) NOT NULL COMMENT 'UUID',
  archive BOOLEAN NOT NULL DEFAULT FALSE,
  PRIMARY KEY (id, scenario)
);

# aim at this:
INSERT INTO entries (id, scenario, archive) VALUES ('id1', 'scenario1', false)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE archive = VALUES(archive);

INSERT INTO entries (id, scenario, archive) VALUES ('id1', 'scenario2', false)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE archive = VALUES(archive);

INSERT INTO entries (id, scenario, archive) VALUES ('id2', 'scenario1', false)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE archive = VALUES(archive);

# try duplicate composite with updated archive.
INSERT INTO entries (id, scenario, archive) VALUES ('id1', 'scenario1', true)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE archive = VALUES(archive);
```

From there, you can also force archive to true like `UPDATE archive = true`, or

Comment: It seems to work in 8.0 when I do not use `?` in the `VALUES`, but now I am curious why.

Comment: @Edward are you using a Driver and Query Builder to connect from a coding language to Mysql? If so, do you use RAW in the query builder? Does the query builder support the `ON DUPLICATE UPDATE` statements?

Comment: Correct, using Go's MySQL driver. Let me verify, it has not had any issues in the past, but this is the first time I using it with a composite primary key.

Comment: Ok good. Then, did you pass the 3 variables to fill the 3 `?` ? For example, it might looks like this for Go's : `db.ExecContext(context.Background(),query, "id1", "scenario1", false);`. I see they say you can interpolate params to inject the values in query before execution, and also there is multi statements option which allows to execute multiple statements, but you must provide ALL the variables in the first statement. Don't have experience with Golang.